# Format inputed digits to US phone number to format (###) ###-####

Tags: ios, swift, format, nsmutablestring

I used this code but the issue I am having is it does not work if texfield is empty (index out of bounds) and the other issue if the user does not change the phonenumber and hit Save button it will execute the code again and insert the "((" and "--".

Any ideas about what I can do?

```
var stringts: NSMutableString = self.ts.text
stringts.insertString("(", atIndex: 0)
stringts.insertString(")", atIndex: 4)
stringts.insertString("-", atIndex: 5)
stringts.insertString("-", atIndex: 9)
self.ts.text = stringts
```

Comment: Are you formatting the text while entering?

Comment: I would like that feature, but my code formats the textfield after I click "Save"

Comment: Wait a minute, I have done that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364055/formattting-phone-number-in-swift use this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can validate the input while entering from the user. Use the `UITextFieldDelgate` to do so:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let str = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if textField == txtFieldPhoneNumber{

        return checkEnglishPhoneNumberFormat(string, str: str)

    }else{

        return true
    }
}
```

Function to validate the input:

```
func checkEnglishPhoneNumberFormat(string: String?, str: String?) -> Bool{

    if string == ""{ //BackSpace

        return true

    }else if str!.characters.count < 3{

        if str!.characters.count == 1{

            txtFieldPhoneNumber.text = "("
        }

    }else if str!.characters.count == 5{

        txtFieldPhoneNumber.text = txtFieldPhoneNumber.text! + ") "

    }else if str!.characters.count == 10{

        txtFieldPhoneNumber.text = txtFieldPhoneNumber.text! + "-"

    }else if str!.characters.count > 14{

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What function do I need to call? Can you provide an example how would you call it? Thank you!

Comment: @RayKing You just need to give `delegate` to your `UITextField`. i.e.: `yourTextFieldOutlet.delegate = self`

Comment: I have bug with this code. My other textFields are changing their values when I am typing the phone number. They set to delegate as well and affected by this code.

Comment: Awesome! Appreciated quick response!