# Format phone number in textfield while typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4, uitextfielddelegate

I'm trying to figure out how to format a phone number being entered while typing live.

I saw this post on the function to do that, but I can't figure out what `UITextFieldDelegate` to call.
[Formattting Phone number in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364055/formattting-phone-number-in-swift)

Should I be using this?:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

The function just returns a bool, so I'm unsure how to implement it with the format function from the linked post.

Comment: Please check [AnyFormatKit](https://github.com/luximetr/AnyFormatKit) and [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit)

Comment: yes you have to use this delegate , also you can check solution there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246439/uitextfield-for-phone-number

Comment: show your tried code and what type of output you expect

Comment: This was handy for me: https://ivrodriguez.com/format-phone-numbers-in-swift/