# How can I format a US phone number in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TextField object where the user enters in a phone number. Currently, it looks like normal numbers and I want it to look like a phone format, so (xxx) xxx-xxxx. I tried out by changing the Content Type of the TextField in the Storyboard to "Telephone number", but it didn't help.

Is there any helper function or code that I can use to format the integers in a textfield to look like a phone number (as the user types the numbers)?

Comment: You might look at [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) or [Formattting Phone number in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364055/formattting-phone-number-in-swift) or [Formatting phone numbers in Swift](https://ivrodriguez.com/format-phone-numbers-in-swift/)

Comment: one more alternative https://github.com/Serheo/SHSPhoneComponent